# How can we store .pdf .ppt .txt .doc files into the database?

Tags: database

I wants to store a .pdf , .ppt , .txt .doc etc type files into the database , is there any datatype in dbms to store such type of files or i make some kind of conversion before putting into the database column?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to store such *binary* data is to use a `BLOB` (binary large object).

There are no other specialiced datatypes for binary data available.

Comment: thanks. what is BLOB?

Comment: A `BLOB` is a datatype and is a *binary large object*. Please consult the documentation of your database.

Comment: ok a bundle of thanks